Does voltage rating of wires matter if I only intend to pass a very small amount of current?
I have spools of wires rated for 60 V from the manufacturer. But my application requires 150 V for safety but I am only powering some 4-20 mA sensors with it. The wires are 16 AWG. Can I use these for my application case? or is it gonna be unsafe if I do so?

The current rating of a wire is based on its heating effect due to its resistance. At some point it will melt the insulation and possibly start a fire.
The voltage rating is based on the insulation breakdown voltage. If it's rated at 60 V then the insulation is not safe at 150 V DC. You could experience breakdown between adjacent conductors or between a conductor and skin.

Yes. It matters (kind of obviously; the current doesn't matter to the voltage between your conductor and its environment at all, and that's what matters for the insulation you need).

In practice, if the insulation is thick enough to actually physically hold together as you handle the wires, then it will stand several hundred volts. But if the wire is rated at 60 V, then your insurance will be void if you run them at 61 V or more.
So, who are you going to be bound by? Physics, or your insurance liabilities? There are degrees of safe and unsafe.
Are you selling your application?
